# Building maven project with latest dependencies from nexus repository

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I would like to run a nightly build of my project with dependencies to our own maven artifacts. Our maven artifacts are hosted in our internal nexus repository.
This is what I have so far.

```
    <profile>
        <id>nightly</id>
        <properties>
            <application.server>glassfish-4</application.server>
            <javaee.endorsed.version>7.0</javaee.endorsed.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>my.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>ourartifact</artifactId>
                <version>[1.3,)</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

I define range [1.3,) which means maven should use highest version but minimum 1.3. What I see is that maven only considers the dependencies from the local repository (e.g. 1.6) while there is a newer version in our nexus repository (e.g. 1.8).
Our repositories are mentioned in pom.xml like this

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <url>http://h2601200.stratoserver.net/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        <id>maven-releases</id>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <url>http://h2601200.stratoserver.net/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        <id>maven-snapshots</id>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

How do I make maven check our nexus repository also?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have   ```<repositories>     <repository> ...    </repository> </repositories>``` defined in your pom.xml?

Comment: @gtiwari333 The repositories are mentioned in <distributionManagement> tags (see edited answer). I will take your hint and try with additional <repositories> entry. Thanks.

Comment: That's the problem. ``distributionManagement`` is for deploy. ``repositories`` is to download them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your nexus repository in repositories -> repository section.

- `distributionManagement` is used to deploy your artifacts while doing `mvn deploy`
- `repositories` is where you define your artifactory URLs to download jar files

```
<project>
...

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-company-nexus</id>
      <name>My Company's Nexus Repo</name>
      <url>https://my-company.repo.com/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    ...
  </repositories>

...
</project>
```